# schedule in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, schedule

I created a command scheduler in laravel,
in the method scheduler i have :

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
    $schedule->command('UpdateTest')->everyMinute()->timezone('Europe/Paris');
}
```

and  in my function handle() i have :

```
function handle(){
    \Log::info('La tâche planifiée a été exécutée à : ' .now());
}
```

when i execute the `php artisan schedule:run` the command instruction  executes most normally in the world but it does not repeat itself every minute as I specified whereas bat when typing the php artisan schedule:list command I see although every minute that passes it updates me the next time it has to execute this command. Thank you in advance for your answers

I tried a lot of things but I can't

Comment: You must write in English here. And please also read [ask] and [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) before you [edit] your question. Thanks.

Comment: ...and you still need to format the code properly as per the guidance I provided above. Don't edit the question until you're fully ready!

Comment: Formatting still wasn't right...you know there's a preview of the question shown below where you're typing?? Fixed it for you, and voted to re-open

Comment: Have you set up a cron job that runs `php artisan schedule:run` every minute?

Answer (score 0):

To enable auto-starting Laravel Scheduler, you should set cron job, that executes every minute.

On your server open Crontab file:

```
crontab -e
```

Add something like that to your Crontab file:
**(change the path to Artisan command of your project!)**

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /your/artisan/path/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

* * * * * means that the job executes every minute!
```

Hope this helps! :)